# get rows by specific TMZ

Tags: php, yii, timezone

I have all time stamp columns(which are actually currently set as datetime type) in DB inserted according to GMT timezone.
so, When a user inserts data the time stamp is by GMT

for example:
row time stamp is: 2014/01/17 01:00 (GMT)
the user time zone is GMT -5, so the user actually did the action at 2014/01/16 21:00

In my site the user can set the time zone for his session.
Is there a way to select the rows according to specific time zone? so that is he searchs
for rows in dates: 2014/01/10 - 2014/01/16
He will get that row.
Using Yii if that helps.

Comment: I think you have to code for it, I don't know if there are built-in functions for that

Comment: This may help you. check here [Local time zones and locales](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/197/local-time-zones-and-locales/)